# Ho to convert CSV file into SQL file easily?

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to convert the data in a CSV file into SQL queries. What is the easiest and the fastest method to convert a CSV into an SQL file?

Comment: Load data infile

Comment: Probably to load it into a table and then output a dump of the table

Comment: we can open a .CSV file in Excel, and then write an Excel formula `="insert into mytable values ('"&REPLACE(A2,"'","''")&"','"&REPLACE(B2,"'","''")&"')"`

Comment: Thanks for your comments <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's an easy method to do that.**

1. Copy your CSV data to your clipboard using a text editor.
2. Go to this [CSV to SQL converter](https://csvtosql.com) website and paste your CSV lines.
3. Click "Convert".
4. Copy the converted SQL queries.
5. Paste those lines in a text editor and save the file into a .sql file.

Comment: That's the method I wanted